# Is it possible to manage a lightsail instance by multiple accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Within our AWS organization we have multiple accounts. When a user creates a lightsail instance within its account it is only visible to this specific account. Is it possible to make the instance visible to all accounts in an organization group, or to the root group at the least?

Edit: Changed to the correct terms, I mixed up accounts and users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When a user creates a lightsail instance it is only visible to this specific user.*

That isn't strictly correct.  It should be visible to other users in the same account as the user that created it... but the visibility can't be extended beyond that account boundary, even within organizations.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I mixed up the correct terms. I've edited my question on this point.

Comment: Same answer, I'm afraid.  Lightsail instances are only visible in the account that created them.  Anyone can access them if their SSH key is authorized, if course... but they aren't visible in the console.